# Installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 over an Antergos install, missing /home

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, data-recovery, ubuntu-mate

I had an Antergos install utilizing a second hdd as my `/home` folder and now decided to switch to Ubuntu Mate.

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 (Mate version 1.12.1), and during setup, choose to replace the `/`, `/boot`, and `swap` directories and formatted them, but selected to use the same partition for `/home` but did **NOT** format.

Used the same username and password and after install, Mate's file manager shows just empty default folders.

HOWEVER - the partition is "missing" 394 GB; the size of my previous `/home` folder. (partition shows as 1 TB, 606 GB free.)

Is there a way to recover my files? It certainly looks like they must still be there but for some reason Mate doesn't "see" them.

ls from within /home shows:
    `myusername`

ls from within /myusername gives:
    `Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu MATE? Please add the version number to your post.

Comment: Maybe Ubuntu installer has created second folder in your /home?
Can you show me result of <code>ls /home</code>?

Comment: Updated to reflect Ubuntu16.04/Mate 1.12.1 (Installed from the Ubuntu Mate distro)

Comment: Results of ls in /home is:
    /myusername

ls in /myusername gives:
    Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos

Comment: Answer located - https://askubuntu.com/questions/617307/problem-accessing-old-data-on-btrfs-home-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Just had to remount the btrfs disk in another directory, which showed the missing data; apparantly /home was mounted to @home...